# Datagrid loads only one result in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, service, datasource, ria

I have a ria domaindatasource that is providing the items for a datagrid. The datagrid however, is only loading one of the results and there are at least 3 results being returned. Why would this be? 
Here is the Code

```
            <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsEnabled="False" x:Name="prevSchoolDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data, ElementName=gridDomainSource}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" AlternatingRowBackground="#AD71BBFF" Margin="2,8" MinColumnWidth="100" >
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="schoolColumn" Binding="{Binding SchoolName}" Header="School" CanUserSort="True"  />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="awardColumn" Binding="{Binding Award}" Header="Award"  />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="creditColumn" Binding="{Binding Credit}" Header="Credit" CanUserSort="True"  />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="studyColumn" Binding="{Binding Study}" Header="Study"  />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dateAttendedColumn" Binding="{Binding DateAttended}" Header="Date Attended" IsReadOnly="True"  />
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

and the domain datasource

```
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource PageSize="50" AutoLoad="True" x:Name="gridDomainSource" QueryName="GetPreviousSchoolsQuery" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <my:ApplyDataContext />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
            <riaControls:Parameter ParameterName="email" Value="{Binding Text, ElementName=EmailTB}" />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

Comment: Can you provide any details of the server side code, or is it just linq to entities with an EF model? How do you confirm 3 records are returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had set the wrong datakey in the incoming model. So the client was binding wrongly.